# How to declare that a function itself has a certain type?

Tags: python, types, mypy

Say I have a function that takes other functions as arguments:

```
Metric = Callable[List[float], float]
def metric_doubler(metric: Metric, lst: List[float]):
    return 2*metric(lst)
```

And I want to write other functions and declare that they have type `Metric`, e.g.

```
def my_mean(lst: List[float]) -> float:
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)
```

Is there a way to assert that `my_mean` in this case has type `Metric`? In particular, the real use case is when I have a lot of such functions, and want to catch errors if I need to change the type of `Metric`.

Comment: Do you mean "return" type?

Comment: I mean the entire type of the function: my_mean as written can be used anywhere a `Callable[List[float], float]` is accepted, but I would like some way of declaring that in the code. As far as I know there's no syntax like `my_mean: Metric` allowed

Comment: It seems that a `my_mean: Metric` annotation at module level might do something useful. (I haven't tried it.)

Comment: I would be very interested in an answer supported by 3.7 typing

Comment: You want to declare or assert?

Comment: Declare (ideally.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually think this is something that's necessary to explicitly check -- just write your code as normal, and constantly run mypy against it.

If you end up accidentally introducing an inconsistency while refactoring some code, mypy will inform you about those mismatches.

So, if you have code that does `metric_doubler(my_mean, something)` and change the definition of `Metric` without also changing `my_mean`, mypy will complain about that function call.

(This is one of the benefits of static typing! If everything is typed, you can refactor more fearlessly since your tooling can detect mistakes and mismatches for you -- you often don't need to put in any extra work beyond adding types.)

If you want to make absolutely sure everything matches, you could perhaps add a few extra unit tests. E.g. maybe add a unit test that looks like:

```
def test_my_mean() -> None:
    assert metric_doubler(my_mean, something) == something_else
```

Then, run mypy against both your full codebase and your tests.

Or even more simply:

```
def expects_metric(x: Metric) -> None: pass

def test_my_mean() -> None:
    expect_metric(my_mean)
```

I think the first form (where you bundle a runtime check along with static checks) is more useful though.